# Rename the ambiguous RT tag to request-tracker

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

RT can mean many different things like

- Real-Time
- Windows RT
- Rail Train
- re-tweet
- [random number generation from t-distribution](https://rdocumentation.org/packages/hisemi/versions/1.1-0/topics/rt)
- [running total](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35047128) (tag replaced in question)
- [a file load error in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76619013/absolute-newbie-question-why-cant-i-open-my-dataset) (tag replaced in question)

[Houlmes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3841222/houmles) made a nice suggestion to rename the [rt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rt) to [request-tracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/request-tracker).

Comment: It would be nice to see a bit more meat to the request, like "of the 92 questions tagged [rt], 65 are about Request Tracker" (with a link to the product page, and actual counts). Perhaps a better tag wiki that isn't wholesale copy-pasta from the website...

Comment: Pretty sure it means "running total" in that last one.

Comment: Good idea Heretic Monkey, I've started a list instead.

Comment: [\[sphinx\] \[rt\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sphinx+rt) are presumably all supposed to be [[tag:real-time]].